# How to search and replace a word on multiple occurrence

Tags: perl

Can anyone please tell me how can I search a word in a text file and replace first 2 occurrences with one value and next 2 occurrences with another value and so on using perl script? Is that possible? Below command just replaces all cat1, cat2, cat3 etc. to dog1, but I want to replace cat1,cat2 to dog1 and cat3, cat4 to dog3.

```
s/cat[0-9]/dog1/g;
```

Below is the script that I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $file = 'C:\Temp\test.txt';
rename($file, $file . '.bak');
open(IN, '<' . $file . '.bak') or die $!;
open(OUT, '>' . $file) or die $!;
while(<IN>)
{
    $_ =~ s/cat[0-9]/dog1/g;
    print OUT $_;
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

Input:

```
Replacement value1: dog51
Replacement value2: dog23
Replacement value3: dog77
Replacement value4: dog95
```

Existing File:

```
<some texts>
test cat01 text
test cat32 text
test cat83 text
test cat54 text
test cat92 text
test cat13 text
test cat62 text
test cat23 text
```

File after replacement:

```
<some texts>
test dog51 text
test dog51 text
test dog23 text
test dog23 text
test dog77 text
test dog77 text
test dog95 text
test dog95 text
```

Comment: Yes, there can be upto 8-10 lines with the same search word followed by some digit but I want to replace every 2 occurrence with different values.

Comment: Try the following operation `$_  ~= s/\bcat(\d)\b/dog($1)/g;` - it looks for separately standing word `cat` followed with digit, stores digit and replaces cat with followed same digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [s///](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s) (especially the `e` modifier).  This replaces even numbers with N-1.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/cat(\d+)/sprintf 'dog%0d', ($1 % 2) ? $1 : ($1-1)/e;
    print;
}

__DATA__
cat1
cat2
cat3
cat4
cat5
cat6
```

Prints:

```
dog1
dog1
dog3
dog3
dog5
dog5
```

`(\d+)` captures the digits after `cat` and stores them in the `$1` variable which is used on the right side of the substitution.

---

After an update to the Question, it looks like the replacement values should be random:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $cnt = 0;
my $n;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/cat\d/) {
        $cnt = ($cnt) ? 0 : 1;
        $n = randint() if $cnt;
        s/cat(\d+)/dog$n/;
    }
    print;
}

sub randint {
    return sprintf '%02d', int rand 100;
}

__DATA__
test cat01 text
test cat32 text
test cat83 text
test cat54 text
test cat92 text
test cat13 text
test cat62 text
test cat23 text
```

Prints:

```
test dog38 text
test dog38 text
test dog46 text
test dog46 text
test dog98 text
test dog98 text
test dog59 text
test dog59 text
```

A different set of numbers will be displayed each time the code is run.

Answer (score 2):

According OP there is no correlation in input and output numbering.

In such situation probable solution is hash mapping *input values* to *output values*.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
        'cat1' => 'dog1',
        'cat2' => 'dog1',
        'cat3' => 'dog3',
        'cat4' => 'dog3'
    );

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    $line =~ s/\b($_)\b/$hash{$1}/g for keys %hash;
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
some sentence cat1 goes here
some cat3 sentence goes here
some sentence goes cat1 here
some sentence cat34 goes here
cat4 some sentence goes here
```

Output

```
some sentence dog1 goes here
some dog3 sentence goes here
some sentence goes dog1 here
some sentence cat34 goes here
dog3 some sentence goes here
```

Sample code for predefined double replacement (for problem description in altered question)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my($index,$counter) = (-1,-1);

my @input = (
        'Replacement value1: dog51',
        'Replacement value2: dog23',
        'Replacement value3: dog77',
        'Replacement value4: dog95'
    );
    
@input = map { s/Replacement value\d: // && $_ } @input;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if( $line =~ /cat\d{2}/ ) {
        ++$index unless ++$counter%2;
        $line =~ s/\bcat\d{2}\b/$input[$index]/;
    }
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
<some texts>
test cat01 text
test cat32 text
test cat83 text
test cat54 text
test cat92 text
test cat13 text
test cat62 text
test cat23 text
<some text>
```

Output

```
<some texts>
test dog51 text
test dog51 text
test dog23 text
test dog23 text
test dog77 text
test dog77 text
test dog95 text
test dog95 text
<some text>
```

Comment: cat1, cat2 in the file will not be always cat1,cat2. It can be different like cat34 and my replacement value will not be same as it is read from different file. I have updated my question with input and output details.

Comment: Then you  have to update `%hash` to reflect this factor.